# CSS percentage measurement in Internet Explorer 11 and Opera

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, opera

I have a problem with percentage measurements in Internet Explorer 11 and Opera. Please have a look at the following example code:

```
<div style="position: relative">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 25%">
  </div>
</div>
```

The inner div-element is positioned absolutely with left: 25%. This works perfectly with Firefox, Chorme or Safari. But Internet Explore and Opera are using left: 25px instead of left: 25%. Pixel and percent are obviously not the same and that's why the inner div looks a little bit "displaced" in IE and Opera.

Does anyone how to get around this problem?

Many thanks in advance for your efforts.

Regards

Comment: I don't have Opera here, but IE11 does not have the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/n8sw0rrv/

Comment: Hi! Thank your for your answer. If you want you may have a look at [link](http://www.rocknroll-weilheim.de). There is a pictureslider with a black div that shows some information. I've used Firefox 47.0.1 and Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.18314 to check the slider. Firefox uses left 25% whereas Internet Explorer left 25px to position the div. I've doublechecked my CSS-Files. There is no left: 25px in there.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Surely not all of the stylesheets and the scripts on your page are necessary to duplicate the problem.

Comment: That said, I do see in the various inspectors that the div with class `jssor_slider_desc_outer_div` gets a style of `left: 25px` in IE, while it doesn't in FF. Check the script that provides the animation.